# How to install npm package from nodejs script?

Tags: node.js, web, npm

How to install npm package from nodejs script?

Question is ***not*** about simple **installation** npm packages **via terminal**,
it is about **installation via nodejs script**:
Not about this: `npm install express`, but about having `install.js` file with content `npm install express`, which I will execute like `node install.js` and after this it will locally install *express* module in this folder.

*Sorry, but Google and DuckDuckGo are not my friends today(*

**The main problem** is in automatic local installation required packages for my small utility, because global packages are not working in windows.

Comment: https://npmjs.org/api/npm.html

Comment: @Quentin my script cannot find npm(  I think it is a windows problem with global packages, which was a reason of this question. I fall in a recursion

Comment: have you tried "npm install"?

Comment: @GabrielLlamas npm is successfully working in terminal

Comment: See this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957529/can-i-install-a-npm-package-from-javascript-running-in-node-js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [commander.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/commander.js) it allows you to write command line apps using node.

Then you can use the `exec` module.

Assuming you put the following in `install.js`, you just have to do: `./install.js` and it will run `npm install` for you.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var program = require('commander');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var run = function(cmd){
  var child = exec(cmd, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (stderr !== null) {
      console.log('' + stderr);
    }
    if (stdout !== null) {
      console.log('' + stdout);
    }
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log('' + error);
    }
  });
};

program
  .version('0.1.3')
  .option('i, --install ', 'install packages')
  .parse(process.argv);



if (program.install) {
  run('npm install');
}


var count = 0;


// If parameter is missing or not supported, display help
program.options.filter(function (option) {
  if(!(option.short == process.argv[2]))
    count++
});

if(count == program.options.length)
  program.help();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, but for using this I need to install npm package commander, and this action returns me to the my question again.

Comment: You can make the part for the command execution **a bit easier** by using [shelljs](https://github.com/arturadib/shelljs) 
```var  shell = require('shelljs');
shell.exec('npm install');```

Comment: Heh, but how to use commanderJS before `npm install` ? It is paradox. This should not use libs to do so. Only native node functions.

Answer (score 3):

*NOTE: I don't think this fulfills all the requirements of your question, because at the end you state that you can't find `npm`...so maybe your question would be better titled "How to install npm package without npm?"--yikes! But it addresses the title, "How to install npm package from nodejs script?"*

I've just been shown another alternative to do this: the module [npmi](https://github.com/maxleiko/npmi). While this is still another module dependency, it does at least work without a *nix shell script environment, which I think the other answer here (about `commander.js`) does. And, if you look inside the code for `npmi.js`, you'll find it's very short and merely uses the npm module directly in the node script--which you can do yourself if you don't want to add the npmi module.

So in our case we needed a way to install modules without requiring a *nix shell script (to support Windows users), and this fits the bill nicely.

That still doesn't help you if you can't `require('npm')`. Only thing I can think of there is trying likely absolute paths...you can `require('C:\Program Files\Node\packages\x`)`, I think--or wherever node's global packages are stored (per user?). Wrap a couple of attempts in try/catch or test for the file's existence first and try to require the npm module whenever you find where the global packages are actually installed? You might tick off a malware scanner :-), but it might work.