# Install programmatically a NPM package providing its version

Tags: node.js, npm

I found [how to install npm packages programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15957574/1420197) and the code works fine:

```
var npm = require("npm");
npm.load({
    loaded: false
}, function (err) {
  // catch errors
  npm.commands.install(["my", "packages", "to", "install"], function (er, data) {
    // log the error or data
  });
  npm.on("log", function (message) {
    // log the progress of the installation
    console.log(message);
  });
});
```

If I want to install the first version of `hello-world` package, how can I do this in the NodeJS side, using `npm` module?

I know that I can use child process, but I want to choose the `npm` module solution.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

NPM NodeJS API is not well documented, but checking the code helps up.

[Here](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/blob/a362c3f1919987419ed8a37c8defa19d2e6697b0/lib/install.js#L16-L29) we find the following string:

```
install.usage = "npm install"
              + "\nnpm install <pkg>"
              + "\nnpm install <pkg>@<tag>"
              + "\nnpm install <pkg>@<version>"
              + "\nnpm install <pkg>@<version range>"
              + "\nnpm install <folder>"
              + "\nnpm install <tarball file>"
              + "\nnpm install <tarball url>"
              + "\nnpm install <git:// url>"
              + "\nnpm install <github username>/<github project>"
              + "\n\nCan specify one or more: npm install ./foo.tgz bar@stable /some/folder"
              + "\nIf no argument is supplied and ./npm-shrinkwrap.json is "
              + "\npresent, installs dependencies specified in the shrinkwrap."
              + "\nOtherwise, installs dependencies from ./package.json."
```

My question is about the version, so we can do: `hello-world@0.0.1` to install `0.0.1` version of `hello-world`.

```
var npm = require("npm");
npm.load({
    loaded: false
}, function (err) {
  // catch errors
  npm.commands.install(["hello-world@0.0.1"], function (er, data) {
    // log the error or data
  });
  npm.on("log", function (message) {
    // log the progress of the installation
    console.log(message);
  });
});
```

I didn't test, but I am sure that we can use any format of the `install.usage` solutions.

I wrote a function that converts the `dependencies` object in an array that can be passed to the `install` function call.

`dependencies:`

```
{
   "hello-world": "0.0.1"
}
```

The function gets the path to the `package.json` file and returns an array of strings.

```
function createNpmDependenciesArray (packageFilePath) {
    var p = require(packageFilePath);
    if (!p.dependencies) return [];

    var deps = [];
    for (var mod in p.dependencies) {
        deps.push(mod + "@" + p.dependencies[mod]);
    }

    return deps;
}
```

Comment: This is great, but, how do you install GLOBALLY using npm programatically?

Comment: @cSn Checking the code I found [this snippet](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/a362c3f1919987419ed8a37c8defa19d2e6697b0/lib/install.js#L122-L162) - however I don't know how the code should look like... Maybe you can ask a question.

Comment: @cSn - you can pass `global: true` to `npm.load`'s options

Comment: version of `createNpmDependenciesArray` for 2021:

return Object.entries(require(packageFilePath).dependencies).map(([name, version]) => `${name}@${version}`)

Comment: As for 2022 this solution doesn't work anymore, npm >8.0.0 deprecated programmatic API, therefore `var npm = require("npm");` inside the project is no longer possible.

Answer (score 8):

As I'm doing this kind of implem A LOT for my work I wrote a simple, yet efficient, nodeJS module to handle the process easily.

[Github repository of npmi](https://github.com/maxleiko/npmi)

or

```
npm install npmi
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm the author of module that allow to do what you have in mind.
See [live-plugin-manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-plugin-manager).

You can install and run virtually any package from NPM, Github or from a folder.

Here an example:

```
import {PluginManager} from "live-plugin-manager";

const manager = new PluginManager();

async function run() {
  await manager.install("moment");

  const moment = manager.require("moment");
  console.log(moment().format());

  await manager.uninstall("moment");
}

run();
```

In the above code I install `moment` package at runtime, load and execute it. At the end I uninstall it.

Internally I don't run `npm` cli but actually download packages and run inside a node VM sandbox.

To install a specific version just use:

```
  await manager.install("moment", "2.20.1");
```

Answer (score 0):

When I'm writing an app that has dependencies I use the package.json file and include it in the directory with my app. It looks maybe a bit like this.

```
{
     "name": "MyApp",
     "description": "My App.",
     "version": "0.0.1",
     "dependencies": {
        "express": "3.4.3",
        "socket.io": "0.9.16"
     }
}
```

I think you can use similar format to install with NPM from command line. With package.json you just do  npm install -d    (assuming the -d stands for "dependencies")

You're question is about doing it programatically.  Have you tried simple adding a second argument like  ("npm@version #")?

If I were doing it programmatically I might try something like this:

```
   var pjson = require('./package.json');
```

That way I can maintain version control and use the simplicity of the package.json file.

I added some more info in the comments, in case you haven't looked yet, here are the docs for npm install.  https://npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-install.html

I've been unable to dig up any other specific information on your specific case, perhaps there is no method to install by version programmatically, but that wouldn't make sense, it has to be doable.

Comment: I think I was not so clear. Suppose that I want to install `express` with `3.4.3` version. When calling `install` I pass an array of strings that mean the package names. What can I pass to install `express 3.4.3`?

Comment: Updated my answer, I think best way would actually be to use require('./package.json');

Comment: Please see how npm module works. Requiring the `package.json` file doesn't help.

Comment: command line is npm install <name>@<version range>, try "express@3.4.3". Otherwise I'm afraid I've hit the limit of my node/npm knowledge.