# Is it okay to include npm in devdependencies in package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I came across a nodejs repo that included npm in devdependencies. What would be the case that requires such config? Because, installing devdependencies already requires npm.

Comment: Dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies

Comment: Not really. It doesn't explain anything about NPM as a dependency.

Comment: Including npm on a version will gurantee that this version of npm is available when using your package. The same is possible for node as well. TL;DR: It's a way of making sure the right version is used

Comment: https://twitter.com/maybekatz/status/958157474397171712

Comment: @Dominik +1 on 
Locking node version 
$ npm install node@7
And one-off run with a specific node version
$ npx -p node@6 npm test

Comment: Are you sure if version of npm mentioned in devdependencies will be used when we run "npm run test" ?

Comment: @naveenchandru No. Only if you explicitly run `npm` it through script, e.g. `"scripts": { "test": "npm run test2", "test2": "..." }`. It first runs global NPM and then local NPM version. But this doesn't matter because `npm run` is not a thing where npm versions behave differently (at least now).

Comment: @estus Yes. That clarifies about global npm picking the mentioned npm version. Also, it may not make sense to use a specific npm version as such. But, good to know about the possibilities and behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This makes sense if a repository uses NPM CLI internally and relies on specific NPM version instead of globally installed NPM, because the behaviour may be changed between major releases:

```
devDependencies: {
  "npm": "^2"
}
```

While

```
devDependencies: {
  "npm": "*"
}
```

won't make much sense, except that it will likely use latest stable NPM version, despite which version was installed globally on local system.

This also makes sense if NPM is used [programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20686244/install-programmatically-a-npm-package-providing-its-version) because global packages cannot be normally `require`d.

Answer (score 0):

Modules which is required for your local development and does not required for production environment can be listed under devDependencies. Its is good to have devDependencies.

- npm install will install both "dependencies" and "devDependencies"
- npm install --production will only install "dependencies"
- npm install --dev will only install "devDependencies"

Comment: This does not explain about the usage of "npm" as dependency/devdependency.