# Should I have npm as dependency in package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm

If you accidentally execute `npm i npm` it adds npm as a dependency to the package.json and adds entries to the package-lock.json.

Should I revert this? Or does it actually make sense to have npm as dependency in the package.json?

Comment: Unless you're `require()`ing `npm`, no.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50399097/is-it-okay-to-include-npm-in-devdependencies-in-package-json

Comment: Is there a way to require a minimum npm version in my dev team? I thought maybe having npm in package.json might do this.

Comment: @el-lugy Is there a reason you need a particular version of NPM?  A lot of people don't even use NPM, they use Yarn and such...

Answer (score 5):

`npm` or other package managers are meant to be installed globally.

If you wish to specify the minimum `npm` version for your project, you could add this to `package.json`

```
"engines" : {
  "npm" : ">=x.x.x"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No, you don't need to have NPM as the dependency in `package.json` file.