# Auto update node project from github

Tags: node.js, github, npm

I wrote a node project and upload the code to github. The project is running form a raspberry pi. I used npm forever-service to run the app on boot.

Is there a way when I change the github code (project code) the project automatically updates itself and restarts the app or reboots the pi and starts the app with the new updated code?

Comment: You need ```webhooks``` check out this post http://thesociablegeek.com/node/github-continuous-deployment-to-a-raspberry-pi/ is very helpful

Comment: For node you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-webhooks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a self-updating node package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35485250/how-to-make-a-self-updating-node-package)