# NPM show update progress programmatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package-management, nwjs

I want to use NPM as the update engine for a [NWJS](https://nwjs.io/) desktop app.

I know its possible to hook up to the NPM api to [programatically install packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957529/can-i-install-a-npm-package-from-javascript-running-in-node-js/15957574#15957574) and my understanding is that the same API can be leveraged for NPM updates.

I'd like is to show a progress bar to users that gives users an indication of how far they are through the update process.

Is it possible to do an `npm update` programmatically with a callback that shows progress as a percentage of all packages updated?