# How to run npm pack command from my application?

Tags: node.js, npm

How to run `npm pack` command from my node application?

something like this:

```
const npm = require('npm')
const result = npm.pack('sourcefolder', 'targetdir');

//result ==== down..
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I install a NPM package from javascript running in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957529/can-i-install-a-npm-package-from-javascript-running-in-node-js)

Comment: no, var npm = require('npm'); is not longer exist..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to run `npm pack` command to create tarball.

Just use `tar` package:

```
const tar = require('tar');
const fstream = require('fstream');

function pack({ path, target }) {
  fstream
    .Reader({ path, type: 'Directory' })
    .pipe(tar.Pack({ noProprietary: true }))
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(target));
}

const name = 'your-folder-package';

pack({
  path: path.join(__dirname, 'packages', name),
  target: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/packages', `${name}.tar`),
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything that can be ran from command line can be ran from JS, so yes:

```
require('child_process').exec('npm pack', console.log)
```