# Is there an easy way to manage state in a node/JS module by using programatically parts of npm logic?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, build

Let's say we want to replicate part of the functionality `npm` has, namely, we want to know if `node_modules` is synced with the current state of `package.json` and `package-lock.json`, so that, if it's not, launch `npm ci` (if possible also programatically). Essentially we don't want to incur into the penalty of running `npm ci` (which can take several seconds) but do something a bit less simplistic than checking the date of `node_modules` against `package.json`.

I have checked out the dependencies of `npm`, and there does not seem to be one that carries that logic. `arborist` is more related to dependencies and its storage, `pacote` deals with packages. So it must be something in `npm` itself. Also, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15957574/891440) we shouldn't really try and run npm from outside the CLI so I wonder if that kind of logic (which is probably used elsewhere, like yarn or grunt) is available from some other package.

At the end of the day, I want a logic similar to the one used by `make`: update stuff if downstream dependencies have changed somehow. `node_modules` vs. `package.json` is an example... But there could be use cases where we would also need it. At the end of the day, what I'm looking for are off-the-shelf node.js modules that would help me create a `make`-like tool in JavaScript.

Comment: `checking the date of node_modules`  Be careful with that approach, caught me out when trying create some auto generated build tools, this was due to NPM using back to future dates,  https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20439  Apparently this was for some tarball consistency builds, but of course instead of fixing the issue at source, NPM dev's decided to break NPM logic instead.

Comment: @Keith which is why, if possible, I'd like to reuse `npm`s logic instead of that.

Comment: @Keith also, was that an April's fools release?

Comment: No, I don't believe it was an April fools.. :) ..  But if you want to see how NPM does thing under the hood, you could maybe look at the source -> https://github.com/npm/cli

Comment: @Keith right, I've tried that... and quitted. Every command has its own file, so that's easy. But then... it gets complicated. Bad comes to worse, I guess that's the only way...