# Is there any disadvantage of adding npm dependency on demand instead of optional dependency?

Tags: node.js, npm, package, dependencies

I want to add a package whenever it is required in my code than adding an optional dependency. Is there any disadvantage of this approach?
Example:

```
this.install('test-package');
```

Instead of in package.json

```
"optionalDependencies": {
    "test-package": "^1.0.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used [live-plugin-manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-plugin-manager) for one of my project worked well.

```
import {PluginManager} from "live-plugin-manager";

const manager = new PluginManager();

async function run() {
  await manager.install("moment");

  const moment = manager.require("moment");
  console.log(moment().format());

  await manager.uninstall("moment");
}

run();
```

There are other tools too, I recommend you checking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957529/can-i-install-a-npm-package-from-javascript-running-in-node-js) link if you find anything useful.